# Find location of library on disk using autotools

Tags: autotools

I know that you can search for a specific function within a library using `AC_SEARCH_LIBS`, but this only tells you whether or not a library is in the library path and satisfies certain conditions. Is there an easy way to get the path--or more specifically the prefix of the library that satisfied `AC_SEARCH_LIBS`?

For example, say I wrote

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([dlopen],[dl],[],[])
```

this just lets me do something based on whether or not I find a library named dl containing dlopen, but it does not tell me where that library is on disk.

I need to do this because the build command for one of the programs I'm wrapping requires the *prefix* for the library, and not just a library name.

Comment: can you add a call to pkgconfig to get the path of your library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard way to do what you want except using `pkg-config`. If the library you're looking for provides `.pc` files, you can query for the `libdir` variable of it to figure out where the file likely is (although there is no guarantee of it.)

```
PKG_CHECK_VAR([FOO_LIBDIR], [foo], [libdir])
AC_MSG_CHECKING([foo library path])
AS_IF([test "x$FOO_LIBDIR" = "x"], [
  AC_MSG_FAILURE([Unable to identify foo lib path.])
])
```

You can find more information on `PKG_CHECK_VAR` [on my Autotools Mythbuster](https://autotools.io/pkgconfig/variables.html).

For system libraries and in general libraries there is no standard way to do so — mostly because cross-compiling mean you don't really know what that path will be when you actually run the software.